# populate spinner from string array using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have spinner which I populate from SQLite database. But I want to populate it from string-array:

```
<string-array name="category">
    <item name="accommodation">Accommodation</item>
    <item name="automobile">Automobile</item>
    <item name="credit cards">Credit Cards</item>
    <item name="donations">Donations</item>
    <item name="entertainment">Entertainment</item>
    <item name="food">Food</item>
</string-array>
```

where `name` I take from SQLite table.
I have method which retrieve `name` from database:

```
public Cursor getAllCategory() {
    mDB = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return mDB.query(CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null,null);
}
```

And in my program I use these names:

```
// spinner
        catSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);
        cursor = adapter.getAllCategory();
        String[] from = new String[] { DataAdapter.CATEGORY_COL_NAME };
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter catAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cursor,
                from, to, 0);
        catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        catSpinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);
```

But I want use names from database, but value that ​​responding to these names(string.xml) use from `string-array`

How I can do this? I want to do this to avoid changing database when I change localization.

Comment: populate spinner from only string array not sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.For getting data into the spinner you have to use `SimpleCursorAdapter` which is given below.

```
  // This is your method of database class which returns cursor
 Public Cursor getAllNames(){
   return mDb.query(table_name, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE}, null, null, null, null, null );
}
```

And use this method in spinner to get items(i.e. Name).

```
 Cursor c = mDbHelper.getAllNames();
 startManagingCursor(c);

  String[] from = new String[]{your_name};
// create an array of the name which you want to bind our data to
  int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

  // This is your simple cursor adapter
   SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

   Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.unique_id ); // This is your spinner
   s.setAdapter(adapter); // Set it to the adapter
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I know how populate spinner from string resources. But how I connect it with sqlite? It is possible or not?

Comment: I have change my post please go through it.

Comment: I have edit my post too. Maybe now more clear. Is it possible to do what i want? thank

Comment: See when you have to populate spinner from database you need to use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and not `ArrayAdapter` and I think you had used it.So I want to know what is the problem you are having in your logcat?

Comment: read this post for more understanding http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=2 this will help you.And let me know

Comment: my question is: can I bind string-array with SQLite?

Comment: your question seems to be so much confusing.Until and unless you elaborate it properly I will not be able to provide you proper solution.